# Delete from Table variable with where condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm deleting data from the table variable based on the condition like below.

```
DELETE FROM @SampleTable WHERE Fname IN (@Fname)
```

In @Fname I have values like 'abc','def','ghi'.

But the delete statement is not deleting the data.
If I pass a SELECT statement in the condition it is deleting.

Comment: You need to use `STRING_SPLIT()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `STRING_SPLIT()` and `REPLACE()` as

```
declare @data table (name varchar(45));

insert @data values
('abc'),('def'),('ghi'),('jkl');

select * from @data;

declare @var varchar(100) = '''abc'',''def'',''ghi''';

delete from @data 
where name in(
              select value 
              from string_split(replace(@var, '''', ''), ',')
             );

select * from @data;
```

<kbd>[Online Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3961f6a468b283ab6bcb0e807c11fe4d)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

I thing, you can try some thing like this.

```
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Query = 'DELETE FROM '+@SampleTable+' WHERE Fname IN ('+@Fname+')'
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @Query
```

Comment: Tried a dynamic approach, it failed with 'must declare a scalar variable @sampleTable'. In this case, I have to make a table variable declare statement in dynamic. but this approach won't suit me I have many delete bassed on different conditions.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> DECLARE  @SampleTable TABLE (Fname VARCHAR(MAX))
> DECLARE @Fname VARCHAR(MAX) ='abc,ghi'
> INSERT INTO @SampleTable(Fname)VALUES('abc'),('bb'),('ghi')
>
> DELETE FROM @SampleTable WHERE Fname IN ( SELECT value from  STRING_SPLIT(@Fname,','));
> SELECT * FROM @SampleTable
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | Fname |
> | :---- |
> | bb    |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c038dd7f7a2b0e8136c418eba610aaa9)*

Comment: Here SampleTable is an actual table, in my case it is a table variable.

Comment: According to what you've write @SandraGuilepZouaouiZandeh, there is no need to use `IN()`, it's just `Fname = @Fname`

Comment: Sure, check the [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f58c3d6ad511126600e2406eb8d3c9d1) I suppose you can understand why.